# What method in date-fns that equivalent to moment().toISOString()

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, date-fns

My old code use momentjs, something like this :

```
moment(createdAt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toISOString()
```

What is the equivalent method on date-fns that will reproduce same result ?

Comment: post an example of createdAt

Comment: i wrote the origin format ( YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss). for the example : "2018-08-27T14:15:39.777"

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
new Date(createAt).toISOString()
```

Comment: Ah.. i just realize that toISOString() is javascript method. i thought it was moment's. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

date-fns has a function: `formatISO()` So, if you want to stay with date-fns you can write:

```
formatISO(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently date fns formatISO does not support miliseconds,
https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/2968

Consequence:

```
date.toISOString() != dateFns.formatISO(date)
```

You should better use js native toISOString() (ECMAScript5)

If not available a polyfill could be used

```
if ( !Date.prototype.toISOString ) {
  ( function() {

    function pad(number) {
      if ( number < 10 ) {
        return '0' + number;
      }
      return number;
    }

    Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
      return this.getUTCFullYear() +
        '-' + pad( this.getUTCMonth() + 1 ) +
        '-' + pad( this.getUTCDate() ) +
        'T' + pad( this.getUTCHours() ) +
        ':' + pad( this.getUTCMinutes() ) +
        ':' + pad( this.getUTCSeconds() ) +
        '.' + (this.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1000).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) +
        'Z';
    };

  }() );
}
```